# How can I sharpen base64 encoded image in php

Tags: php, image, gd

Are there any libraries (preferably free) that I can use to sharpen base64 ecoded images in php.

Hi I am generating a pdf file using mpdf in php that shows base64 encoded image of a person's signature.

The problem is the images do not look very sharp or clear. I am constrained with the size(dimensions) of the image as I need to show 10 images per row.

Currently I output the image using the following bit of code:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,'. $pieces[0] .'" height="15" width="60" />
```

$pieces[0] is the string that comes from mySQL for example(iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ImageMagick.

[ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org)

Here is a base function you can modify.

```
function imagick_sharpen_resized_files($resized_file) {

    $image = new Imagick($resized_file); 

    $size = @getimagesize($resized_file);

    if (!$size)

        return new WP_Error('invalid_image', __('Could not read image size.'), $file);

    list($orig_w,$orig_h,$orig_type) = $size;



    // We only want to use our sharpening on JPG files

    switch($orig_type) {

        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:



    // Automatic Contrast Leveling

    if (get_option('AutoConLev')==true) {

        $image->normalizeImage();

    }



    // Sharpen the image (the default is via the Lanczos algorithm)

        $image->unsharpMaskImage(get_option('Radius'),get_option('Sigma'),get_option('Sharpening'),get_option('Threshold'));



    // Store the JPG file, with as default a compression quality of 92 (default WordPress = 90, default ImageMagick = 85...)

        $image->setImageFormat("jpg");

        $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

        $image->setImageCompressionQuality(get_option('CompressionQuality'));

        $image->writeImage($resized_file); 



            break;

        default:

            return $resized_file;

    }   



    // Remove the JPG from memory

    $image->destroy();



    return $resized_file;

}
```

Hope this helps,

Tim

Comment: thanks @mpactMedia it looks very promising. Can I pass base64 encoded image?Do you have any sample usage for this function.

Comment: Check this out http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php the docs page with function manipulating a base64 image.

Answer (score 0):

Intervention Image is the best tool I know to handle images.

You can input almost any type of images in it (even base64) and do what you want with it.

See the doc here http://image.intervention.io/api/make

Comment: this looks excellent library, thank you for the pointer.